# function syntax is semicolon really needed here

Tags: javascript, syntax

JSHint keeps telling me that this is incorrect.

```
this.x = function( z ) {do stuff}
```

it is reporting there should be a semicolon before the last }

```
this.x = function( z ) {do stuff;}
```

and lint is reporting there should be a semicolon after the )

```
this.x = function( z ); {do stuff}
```

but it seems to be running, is this normal or is it one of those errors that will be ignored if not ran in strict, and which one is the correct answer

Comment: you could also do this too :P `this.x = (function( z ) {do stuff;});`

Comment: You misunderstand the LINT...it is certainly not telling you to put a semicolon after the close-paren of a function definition.

Comment: is that the correct format?

Comment: @JAAulde thanks, I moved the formatting around a bit and the arrow moved to the last } before with all the other lines in the way it looked as I described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lint isn't asking you to add a semicolon after the closing paren as [JAAulde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239567/jaaulde) pointed out.

It is asking you to put a semicolon after the closing curly brace like this:

```
this.x = function( z ) {
    // an instruction with a semicolon;
}; // and this one is for the outer instruction
```

Please note that indentation is of really important to avoid this kind of confusions.

Yes it is mandatory, because it is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) the semicolon refers to the main instruction's purpose in the current case: assignment.

Comment: It's not _mandatory_ because [it will work without it](http://jsfiddle.net/QE5A6/) _depending on what's on the next line._ (Personally I _would_ put a semicolon.)

Comment: Yes you can, but if planning to use JSLint or should I say JSHint which is more compliant `asi`(http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#asi) option is not on by default

Answer (score 0):

The first option is correct.  Semicolon separates statements in JS - it doesn't terminate them.  This does get complicated by some automatic insertion rules but here you are okay. The second is also valid and will keep some overly aggressive tools (jsl) from complaining.  Your third option is just wrong.